# scala forward reference extends over definition of value dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to typecast the columns in the data frame `df_trial` which has all the columns as string, based on an XML file I'm trying to type cast each column.

```
val columnList = sXml \\ "COLUMNS" \ "COLUMN"
val df_trial = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema_allString)
columnList.foreach(i => {
  var columnName = (i \\ "@ID").text.toLowerCase()
  var dataType = (i \\ "@DATA_TYPE").text.toLowerCase()
  if (dataType == "number") {
    print("number")
    var DATA_PRECISION: Int = (i \\ "@DATA_PRECISION").text.toLowerCase().toInt
    var DATA_SCALE: Int = (i \\ "@DATA_SCALE").text.toLowerCase().toInt;
    var decimalvalue = "decimal(" + DATA_PRECISION + "," + DATA_SCALE + ")"
    val df_intermediate: DataFrame =
      df_trial.withColumn(s"$columnName",
                          col(s"$columnName").cast(s"$decimalvalue"))
    val df_trial: DataFrame = df_intermediate
  } else if (dataType == "varchar2") {
    print("varchar")
    var DATA_LENGTH = (i \\ "@DATA_LENGTH").text.toLowerCase().toInt;
    var varcharvalue = "varchar(" + DATA_LENGTH + ")"
    val df_intermediate =
      df_trial.withColumn(s"$columnName",
                          col(s"$columnName").cast(s"$varcharvalue"))
    val df_trial: DataFrame = df_intermediate
  } else if (dataType == "timestamp") {
    print("time")
    val df_intermediate =
      df_trial.withColumn(s"$columnName", col(s"$columnName").cast("timestamp"))
    val df_trial: DataFrame = df_intermediate
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In each branch of the if-else you're using the values called `df_trial` before you've defined them. You'll need to rearrange the code to define them first.

Note: the way you have it, the `df_trial` at the very top is not being used. Depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to change the first `df_trial` to a `var` and remove the `val` from the other usages. (This is probably still wrong since you will be overwriting the same variable multiple times as you loop over `columnList`).